# How to access Bitrise iOS test results from Swift DangerFile?

Tags: swift, xcode, continuous-integration, bitrise, danger

I'm trying to implement danger-swift but I don't know where I can access test results and flag failing ones from Bitrise.

I'm using a plugin for danger-swift called DangerXCodeSummary but I don't know where Bitrise stores test results from xcode-test@2.

DangerFile:

```
import Danger
import DangerXCodeSummary
import Foundation

let danger = Danger()

let testReportPath = "??" // What's the path for the test results?
XCodeSummary(filePath: testReportPath).report()
```

Bitrise script:

```
...
UnitTests:
before_run:
- _ensure_dependencies
after_run:
- _add_build_result_to_pr
steps:
- xcode-test@2: {} # What's the file path for the test results?
- deploy-to-bitrise-io@1: {}
envs:
-   ots:
    is_expand: false
    BITRISE_PROJECT_PATH: MyApp.xcodeproj
- opts:
    is_expand: false
    BITRISE_SCHEME: AppTests
    description: Unit Tests running at every commit.
...

_add_build_result_to_pr:
steps:
- script@1:
    title: Commenting on the PR
    is_always_run: true
    inputs:
    - content: |-
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        # fail if any commands fails
        set -e
        echo "################### DANGER ######################"
        echo "Install Danger"
        brew install danger/tap/danger-swift
        echo "Run danger"
        danger-swift ci
        echo "#################################################"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what outputs the step generates on the Workflow Editor UI, and alternatively in the Step's repository in `step.yml`. For Xcode Test step specifically: https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-test/blob/deb39d7e9e055a22f33550ed3110fb3c71beeb79/step.yml#L287

Am I right that you're looking for the `xcresult` test output? If you are, you can read it from the `BITRISE_XCRESULT_PATH` environment variable (https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-test/blob/deb39d7e9e055a22f33550ed3110fb3c71beeb79/step.yml#L296), which is the output of Xcode Test (once Xcode Test is finished, it sets this environment variable to the `xcresult`'s path). Keep in mind this is in `.xcresult` format (the official Xcode test result format).

Comment: Perfect! I couldn't find the env var for the path to the xcresult.